# Git Flow: Automatically Close Feature Branch After Merged to Master

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge, bitbucket

Summary: I would like to stop team members from closing feature branches and only close feature branches after they have been merged into master.

I have the following git environment in bitbucket:

- `master` (prod)
- `env/stage`
- `env/qa`
- `env/dev`

All `env` branches protected.

All feature branches branch off `env/dev` then when completed, the dev creates a pull request to put the feature into `env/dev` which is reviewed and approved. After `env/dev` its merged into `env/qa` where tests are ran, then `env/stage` to be a release candidate, then released.

Is there a process I could implement or a tool I could use to do the following:

1. Remove team ability to close branches after merged into `env/dev`
2. Only close branches after they have made it up to `master`